# How to correctly configure Snap'd Firefox to open local html-file, generated by Jupyter Notebook launcher?

Tags: permissions, firefox, snap, 21.10, jupyter

I'm currently running Ubuntu MATE 21.10.
As an experiment (to be ready to Firefox deb → Snap migration) I have removed deb-packaged Firefox from it by

```
sudo apt-get autopurge firefox
```

and installed Snap version of Firefox with

```
snap install firefox
```

> ```
> $ snap list firefox 
> Name     Version   Rev  Tracking       Publisher  Notes
> firefox  96.0.2-1  886  latest/stable  mozilla✓   -
> ```

Its permissions are default: only "Use any connected joystick" and "Read access to network settings" are disabled.

Also I have installed Jupyter Notebook from official repositories on this system by

```
sudo apt-get install jupyter-notebook
```

When I launch Jupyter Notebook using `jupyter-notebook` from terminal it shows some greeting message:

> ```
> $ jupyter-notebook 
> [I 18:24:31.237 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/i
> [I 18:24:31.237 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.2.0 is running at:
> [I 18:24:31.237 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=7d0bbefd6ff58eddf9a1dbbd3d63e273282311d5b346cbe3
> [I 18:24:31.237 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7d0bbefd6ff58eddf9a1dbbd3d63e273282311d5b346cbe3
> [I 18:24:31.237 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
> [C 18:24:31.295 NotebookApp] 
>    
>    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
>        file:///home/i/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-2252-open.html
>    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
>        http://localhost:8888/?token=7d0bbefd6ff58eddf9a1dbbd3d63e273282311d5b346cbe3
>     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7d0bbefd6ff58eddf9a1dbbd3d63e273282311d5b346cbe3
> ```

then opens Firefox with error message inside it:

> **Access to the file was denied**
>
> The file at /home/i/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-2252-open.html is not readable.
>
> It may have been removed, moved, or file permissions may be preventing access.

From the same machine I can access this file using terminal

> ```
> $ ls -al /home/i/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-2252-open.html
> -rw-rw-r-- 1 i i 673 Jan 28 18:24 /home/i/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-2252-open.html
> ```

or using deb-packaged Epiphany.

I already know that there is a workaround by visiting localhost's URLs (`http://localhost:8888/?token=7d0bbefd6ff58eddf9a1dbbd3d63e273282311d5b346cbe3`
or `http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7d0bbefd6ff58eddf9a1dbbd3d63e273282311d5b346cbe3`), but it is not user-friendly and break normal expected workflow.

Comment: Don't you need a connection to home? `snap connections firefox`? Mint developers [seems to dislike snap](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3906), did you consider Flatpak alternative?

Comment: The problem is that, by default, it cant access that path any further than /home/i/; This is snaps not having access to dot folders. I have looked everywhere and there is nothing in english on how to make it possible. There is a LOT of "take a look at this link" but no "answer", which makes me think they don't understand what they are reading either (even on this site). I am using Opera snap and i can get to the same results as you. From what I can understand, if I could get Opera to use the "personal-files" interface, then it should be able to access hidden folders/files(firefox in your case)

Comment: I have no idea on how to do that... i am no expert with snaps... But if you do know how to do that, I would appreciate if you'd post that process if it turns out to work for an answer for you. I've only barely looked through the jupyter application, but if there is a config file that you could designate that "/home/i/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-2252-open.html" to be something like /home/i/LOCAL/x/x/xxxx.... or something without a hidden directory, I'm pretty sure that would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a launcher to circumvent the snap restraint.

A simple launcher would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
export JUPYTER_DATA_DIR=/home/$USER/Public
export JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR=/home/$USER/Public

jupyter-notebook
```

...or skip the launcher and set the environment variables wherever convenient.

Answer (score 3):

Err, you cant. I tried to look at hidden directories (.local etc) with different browsers and none work. But hang on there is a workaround: see [this link.](https://www.pythonfixing.com/2022/01/fixed-jupyter-notebook-access-to-file.html)
Your browser will/should open with the link http://localhost:8888/?token=blahblah automatically.

NB: creating and editing the conf file worked but the cleanup didn't work for me.

Create the configuration file by running the command:

`jupyter-notebook --generate-config`

Edit the file

~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

and set:

c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False

Comment: You see the bounty. So please edit your answer and include essential parts to it. I need fully reproducible method in the single answer without visiting third-party sites.

Comment: or add `"use_redirect_file": false` to `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json`

Comment: didn't work for me