# Cannot open Jupyter lab in firefox

Tags: firefox, jupyter

I had not used jupyter for a while, I updated ubuntu, firefox, conda, and jupyter lab, and get the error message in the screenshot, I have reinstalled both jupyter lab and firefox and it just won't open.

Error message in firefox:

[image: Error message in firefox]

Comment: If you are using snap version of firefox, you can find the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217639/jupyter-notebook-access-issue-in-chromium)

Answer (score 0):

A solution (check also https://askubuntu.com/a/1390495/1015711 ) is to
first

i) Create the configuration file by running the command:

`jupyter-notebook --generate-config`

ii) Edit the file

~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

and set:

`c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False`